# In the 1993 Body Snatchers movie, why does Marti have a stepmother?

Tags: body-snatchers

Was there a divorce between her dad and her birth mom, with her birth mom also hating her daughter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About 29 minutes into the runtime, Marti states that her mother died when she (Marti) was seven years old.

> MARTI: **I was, uh, seven when she died.** I didn't expect my dad to get married again. Stupid, huh?
>
> TIM: You must really miss her. What was your mother like?
>
> MARTI: You always remember the good things about people. I miss her.
>
> <sub>[*Body Snatchers (1993)* - transcript](https://subslikescript.com/movie/Body_Snatchers-106452)</sub>